# Saving images from a web page

Tags: python, beginner, web-scraping

I'm just getting my feet on the ground with Python (maybe 3 days now). The only issue with teaching my self is that I have no one to critique my work.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think my algorithm/method for solving this problem is quite promising; but, the code not so much.

The program basically strips a web-page and puts it in to the designated directory. My favorite part is the method for deciding the image's extensions :)

```
import os, re, urllib

def Read(url):
    uopen = urllib.urlopen(url)
    uread = ''
    for line in uopen: uread += line
    return uread

def Find(what, where):
    found = re.findall(what, where)
    match = []
    for i in found:
        i = i[9:-1]
        match.append(i)
    return match    

def Retrieve(urls, loc):
    loc = os.path.realpath(loc)
    os.system('mkdir ' + loc +'/picretrieved')
    loc += '/picretrieved'
    x = 0
    exts = ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.gif', '.png']
    for url in urls:
        x += 1
        for i in exts:
            ext = re.search(i, url)
            if ext != None:
                ext = ext.group()
                urllib.urlretrieve(url, loc + '/' + str(x) + ext)
            else:
                continue


    print 'Placed', str(x), 'pictures in:', loc


def main():
    url = raw_input('URL to PicRetrieve (google.com): ')
    url = 'http://' + url
    loc = raw_input('Location for PicRetrieve older ("." for here): ')
    html = Read(url)
    urls = Find('img src=".*?"',  html)
    print urls
    Retrieve(urls, loc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os, re, urllib

def Read(url):
```

Python convention is to name function lowercase_with_underscores

```
    uopen = urllib.urlopen(url)
```

I recommend against abbreviations

```
    uread = ''
    for line in uopen: uread += line
    return uread
```

Use `uopen.read()` it'll read the whole file

```
def Find(what, where):
    found = re.findall(what, where)
    match = []
    for i in found:
```

avoid single letter variable names

```
        i = i[9:-1]
        match.append(i)
    return match
```

Combine short lines of code

```
 for i in re.findall(what, where):
      match.append(i[9:-1])
```

I think its cleaner this way. Also use capturing groups rather then indexes.

```
def Retrieve(urls, loc):
    loc = os.path.realpath(loc)
    os.system('mkdir ' + loc +'/picretrieved')
```

Use `os.mkdir` rather than using system

```
    loc += '/picretrieved'
```

Use os.path.join to construct paths

```
    x = 0
    exts = ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.gif', '.png']
    for url in urls:
        x += 1
```

use `for x, url in enumerate(urls):`

```
        for i in exts:
            ext = re.search(i, url)
```

Don't use regular expressions to search for simple strings. In this case I think you really want to use `url.endswith(i)`. Also, stop using `i` everywhere.

```
            if ext != None:
                ext = ext.group()
                urllib.urlretrieve(url, loc + '/' + str(x) + ext)
            else:
                continue
```

This continue does nothing

```
    print 'Placed', str(x), 'pictures in:', loc
```

You don't need to use str when you are using print. It does it automatically.

```
def main():
    url = raw_input('URL to PicRetrieve (google.com): ')
    url = 'http://' + url
    loc = raw_input('Location for PicRetrieve older ("." for here): ')
    html = Read(url)
    urls = Find('img src=".*?"',  html)
```

Generally, using an html parser is preferred to using a regex on html. In this simple case you are ok.

```
    print urls
    Retrieve(urls, loc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```